# In appium ,package name and activity name are not auto populated on giving Appium apk path

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am new to appium, started a few days back. When am giving the apk path in appium-android setting, the package name and the launch activity name is not auto populated . It is showing blank [here, package is blank and the same with activity also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khral.png).

Can anyone tell me please where the problem is or am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you using correct apk? This might be because of invalid apk. Revalidate the apk that you are using.

Comment: ya its correct apk. for the first time it auto populated and when am trying for the second time it is not. I have even used other apk for some other app. Still its not working

Comment: Can you please try by unchecking the Package field?

Comment: I tried. On unchecking the package feild it is disable , drop down doesnt work

Comment: can you please share the code what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aapt command in the Android SDK to get the list of activities in a apk file.

```
aapt dump xmltree <apk-file-path> AndroidManifest.xml
```

This will output the AndroidManifest.xml file in a readable format and you can locate the activity names and package names for the apk.

aapt tool can be found in the `<sdk_directory>/build-tools/<version_number>/`

Answer (score 1):

i too encountered with the same issue you had faced .the issue is fixed now. I uninstalled and reinstalled the appium.exe and set up the environment variable for sdk again. as ANDROID_HOME : path to your android sdk